# Simple formula question

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many possible combinations of numbers can be made using 0-9 without using the same number twice any any part. example 1,2,12,1234567890...but never using 1111 or 122 versions...

Any combination that only uses each number one time.

Can someone help.

Additional information!

I have a simple lock box that we have forgotten the combination. We no longer wish to open it (its empty and we know that, but now have a bet in the office as to how many possible number combinations there are to try if someone so wished. There are 10 buttons on it, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 .. no number can be used 2 times as once the number is pressed it cannot be pressed again.

The bet is simple. There are 5 project managers each of us have blocks. CLosest to the actual possible number is the winner, farthest from the actual possible number combinations is the loser and must buy all lunch. Combination possibilities...0-10K, 10,0001-50K, 50,001-100,000, 100,001-500,000, and 500,001-1mil....

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of rearrangement? You want to know how many ways there are to rearrange a set of 1, 2,.., 9 elements and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

The combinations have no more than $10$ digits.

For $1\le n\le 10$, there are $a_n=10\cdot9\cdot\ldots\cdot(10-n+1)$ combinations. This is
$$a_n=\frac{10!}{n!}$$

Then, the total number of combinations is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{10!}{n!}=10!\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n!}\approx10!e$$

**Notice**
Since you have said 'combinations' and not 'numbers' I have counted the combinations that start with $0$.